# <p:autoComplete> does not show up inside <p:inplace>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i want to inplace edit a autoComplete text field:

```
        <h:panelGroup>
        <ui:repeat value="#{cc.attrs.relations}" var="ur">
            <p:panel headerText="Relation">

                <p:inplace  editor="true" >
 <!--                        <p:inputText value="#{ur.relation.name}"
                                 required="true" label="text"/>-->
                    <p:autoComplete  
                                    value="myval"  
                                   />
                </p:inplace>

            </p:panel> 
        </ui:repeat>
    </h:panelGroup>
```

However, this does not work (autocomplete is not shown.).

Do you know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Works for me. Post more of your view and check your browser console for errors

Comment: This is the full body of the cc:implementation tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason autocomplete is not shown is that inplace does not get its label as with i.e. inputText. 
adding label="TheLabel" solves the problem.

```
<h:panelGroup>
    <ui:repeat value="#{cc.attrs.relations}" var="ur">
        <p:panel headerText="Relation">

            <p:inplace  editor="true" label="TheLabel">
<!--                        <p:inputText value="#{ur.relation.name}"
                             required="true" label="text"/>-->
                <p:autoComplete  
                                value="myval"  
                               />
            </p:inplace>

        </p:panel> 
    </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGroup>
```